# Find the smallest ellipse containing a family of ellipses of the same shape

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Given the usual definition of ellipse

$\mathcal{E}(A,c):=\{ x\in \mathbb{R}^2 | (x-c)^\top A (x-c) \le 1 \}$ with $A=A^\top>0 $,

I am trying to solve the following problem

**Problem:** Given an ellipse $\mathcal{E}_2:=\mathcal{E}(A/\alpha^2,c_2)$ with $\alpha>1$ find the smallest value of $\alpha$ such that $\forall\, c_1$, s.t., $\| c_1 - c_2 \| \le d$, $\mathcal{E}_1:=\mathcal{E}(A,c_1) \subseteq \mathcal{E_2}$.

In other words, I trying to find what is the minimum dilatation factor such that $ \mathcal{E_2}$ contains any possibile $\mathcal{E_1} $ (remind that dividing the matrix $A$ by $\alpha^2$, the semiaxes are enlarged of a factor $\alpha$).

My first attemp was to consider this problem geometrically. Consider a circle centered in $c_2$ with radius $d$. All the possible ellipses $\mathcal{E}_1$ have their centre inside this circle. In the attempt to find the worst case, I consider the four ellipses whose center is on the circumpherence and one of the two axis is tangent to the circumpherence (see Fig.1).

[image: Figure 1]

Let's call the semi-axes of a generic ellipse $\mathcal{S(E)}$.
By Fig. 1, it is clear that the containing ellipse $\mathcal{E}_2$ must satisfy the following conditions

1. $\min{\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{E}_2)} \ge d+\min{\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{E}_1)} $, satisfied by $\alpha \ge \dfrac{(d+\min{\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{E}_1)})^2}{\min{\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{E}_1)}^2} $
2. $\max{\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{E}_2)} \ge d+\max{\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{E}_1)} $ satisfied by $\alpha \ge \dfrac{(d+\max{\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{E}_1)})^2}{\max{\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{E}_1)}^2} $

If $ \alpha \ge \dfrac{ (d+\min{\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{E}_1)})^2 }{ \min{\mathcal{S} (\mathcal{E}_1)}^2} \ge \dfrac{(d+\max{\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{E}_1))^2} }{ \max{\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{E}_1)}^2 }$ both condition are satisfied.

Since I am looking for the smallest containing ellipse $\mathcal{E}_2$, i.e., the smallest $\alpha$, I choose $\alpha = \dfrac{ (d+\min{\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{E}_1)})^2 }{ \min{\mathcal{S} (\mathcal{E}_1)}^2}$ (see Fig.2)

[image]

Drawing all the possible ellipses $\mathcal{E}_1$, it seems that this value of $\alpha$ solves the problem (see Fig. 3)

[image: Figure 3]

Do you have any suggestion about how formally prove this conjecture?
Maybe the solution could be easily extended to the 3D case...

Thank you all for your attention!

Answer (score 2):

The value of $\alpha$ is determined by the condition of tangency between the two ellipse $E_1(c_1,1)$ and $E_2(c_2\alpha) $  At the tangency point $r$ we have

$(r - c_1)^T A (r - c_1) = 1 $

$(r - c_2) A (r - c_2) = \alpha^2 $

$A (r - c_1) = \kappa A (r - c_2) $

for some $\kappa \gt 0 $

The last equation implies

$ r - c_1 = \kappa (r - c_2) $

so that

$ (1 - \kappa) r = c_1 - \kappa c_2 $

which simplifies further to

$ r = \dfrac{ c_1 - \kappa c_2 }{1 - \kappa} $

Plug this expression for $r$ into the very first equation

$ ( c_1 (\kappa - 1) + c_1 - \kappa c_2 )^T A ( c_1 (\kappa - 1) + c_1 - \kappa c_2) = (1 - \kappa)^2 $

This reduces to

$ ( c_1 - c_2 )^T A (c_1 - c_2) = \bigg( 1 - \dfrac{1}{\kappa} \bigg)^2$

Whose solution is

$ | 1 - \dfrac{1}{\kappa} | = \sqrt{ (c_1 - c_2)^T A (c_1 - c_2) } $

Noting that $\kappa \lt 1 $ because the first ellipse is smaller than the second ellipse, then

$ \kappa = \dfrac{1}{ \sqrt{(c_1 - c_2)^T A (c_1 - c_2) } + 1 } $

Finally evaluate $r$ with the found value of $\kappa$ and substitute it into the second equation, and this will give $\alpha$.

The following shows an example that I worked out using the above equations.  The smaller fixed ellipse is the blue one centered at $c_1 = (3,6)$, while the scalable one is centered at $c_2 = (5,4) $ and shown in pink.  The orange ellipse is the smallest scaled version of the pink ellipse that covers the first ellipse.

[image]

Comment: One can also prove that the tangency point lies on the line through the centers of the two ellipses.

Comment: Yes, this is evident from the equation for $r$.

Comment: Thank you @WhyHosamWhy! I really appreciated your suggestion of the tangent condition among two ellipses. Unfortunately, this condition does not solve my problem. I realized that I did not explain it very well and I edited my post. I hope now it is more clear for everyone. The point is that I am looking for the dilatation factor $\alpha$ such that ANY ellipse within a known distance is contained in the stretched one. With your condition I can prove that a single ellipse is inside but not all the ones I am interested in. Thank you again for your time and consideration!

Comment: @timon92 do you think the revised version of the post is clearer?